# Network trains well on a grid of shape N but when evaluating on any variation fails

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

For training I randomly generate a grid of shape N contaning values 0 and 1.
There are two actions defined [0,1] and I want to teach a policy using DQN to take action of 0 when the next number is 1 and take action 1 when next number in the array is 0.

I am using DQN, with Keras to create my network

```
Example :
N=11
grid=[ 0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
Agent mark = 0.5
start point=0
current state =[ 0.5,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
action=[0,1]
```

Consider we only move to the right of the array:
The next step should take a VALID action 0 resulting in the following state:

```
Next state=[ 0,0.5,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
```

This is enforced through experience replay.
It trains well and I reach a win rate of 100% (Calculated by solving the same maze consecutively for 10 times.
Now its time to evaluate it on a variation of this grid say:

```
[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0]
```

starting from

```
[0.5,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0]
```

The network fails to predict the correct valid action which in this case is 1.

My network looks like this:

```
Dense
Relu
Dense
Relu
Dense (number_of_actions)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It learned to predict better with more training. The first evaluation was done after 8 hours of training. After close to 36 hours of training it predicting better in variations as well!